# Invalid initializer, CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, initializer, tile, cgpoint

i have this code and on the second line it gives me an error that says invalid initialzer
this is the code:

```
-(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
 CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:position];
 int tileGid = [_meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
 if (tileGid) {
  NSDictionary *properties = [_tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
  if (properties) {
   NSString *collision = [properties valueForKey:@"Collidable"];
   if (collision && [collision compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    return;
   }
  }
 }
 _player.position = position;
}
```

Comment: What's the return type of `tileCoordForPosition:`?

Comment: Check if you're missing a closing bracket } some where in the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you. But when I declare function [tileCoordForPosition] in .h file, everything is built success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use my psychic powers and guess that you accidentally declared `tileCoordForPosition:` as returning a `CGPoint*` (that is, a pointer to a `CGPoint`) rather than a `CGPoint`.

<sub>(It would, however, have been helpful if you'd shown the relevant code so I wouldn't have to fire up the ESP.)</sub>